# Random walk with reflective barriers

Tags: real-analysis, probability, stochastic-processes

Consider a random walk starting at $x_0 \in [0,1]$. At any discrete time step $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the new position is given by: $$x_k = \min\{\max\{x_{k-1}+C_k,0\},1\}$$ where $C_k \sim U(-a,a)$ are i.i.d. uniform random variables with support in $[-a,a]$. In other words, we are moving at random in $[0,1]$ and we have a certain probability to be ''absorbed'' at $0$ or $1$ and then eventually reflected back.

I am trying to find the stationary distribution of this process. Based on simulations, I have the feeling that the stationary distribution must be something like
$$\pi(x) = \alpha \delta_0(x)+ \alpha \delta_1(x)+(1-2\alpha){1}_{[0,1]}(x) $$
where $\alpha$ is the stationary probability of being at the extreme points and ${1}_{[0,1]}$ is the indicator function on $[0,1]$.

Is there any way to find $\pi(x)$ rigorously?

Comment: what happens without the reflecting barrier?

Comment: @DanielAdams In that case, by the CLT, you approach a normal distribution. It is a well-known result. However, you do not have a stationary distribution in that case as the variance blows up in the long run.

Comment: $f(x)=\int_{x-a}^{x+a}f(y)dy$.  So it should increase as you move from just above $0$ to just below $a$

Comment: @Empy2 Can you explain me how you got that?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps there should be a factor $1/2a$ out the front, so the pdf at a point is the average of the pdfs of nearby points.  (Also there is a different equation for $x=0$ and $x=1$.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the discrete version.  Suppose there are $N$ states.
You can move from any state $x$ to any state from $x-m$ to $x+m$ with probability $1/(2m+1)$.
Adjustments are needed for states $1$ and $N$.
Build the transition matrix.  Find its dominant eigenvector and plot it.
Play around with various $N$ and $m$.

Comment: I tried and I get a certain invariant distribution. It is not exactly uniform in between the two extreme points as I thought. What can I deduce about the continuous setting from this?

Comment: I expect, based on the integral equation, there is a step down at $x=a$, and a kink at $x=2a$

Comment: Correct but how can I jump back to the continuous setting from this?

Comment: Start with $f_1(x)=b\delta(x)+b\delta(1-x)+1-2b$.   Apply the integral formula $f_2(x)=\int_{x-a}^{x+a}f_1(y)dy$ to get a $f_2(x)$ which is two deltas plus piecewise-linear.  Apply the integral again to get $f_3$ which is two deltas plus piecewise-quadratic, and so on.

Comment: Sorry  with $1/2a$ factor on the integral.  I don't know what happens when the two ends start to mix in the middle

Comment: Yep, the problem is the endpoints. In the discrete setting, one could at least say that there exists a unique invariant distribution since the underlying MC is aperiodic and ergodic. I guess the same should hold for the continuous model.